# A wave of clues

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I am an involuntary action

I will make you cry

If you force me to stop

---

I am also a knave

of excavation

and of luck

---

I am also a soldier

you can't find me in the heavens

you can't find me in the seas

---

In a lifetime

and upon a time

I am what's missing

---

What could I be?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This lookls like a nice first puzzle/riddle. You should [take the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) for an easy [badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are all

> K-pop fan clubs. The title refers to what is known as the “Korean Wave”.

1)

> “BLINK” are fans of Black Pink. Blinks are involuntary, and if you try not to blink your eyes will water.

2)

> “Blackjacks” are fans of 2NE1. “Knaves” are “jacks”, and the two black suits are spades (excavation) and clubs, more relevantly called clovers (luck).

3)

> A.R.M.Y are fans of BTS. Out of the five branches of the U.S. Armed Forces, the Air Force is in the heavens, and the Navy, Marine Corps, and Coast Guard are in the seas, so the Army remains.

4)

> ONCE are fans of TWICE. This word is missing from the phrases “once in a lifetime” and “once upon a time”.

Comment: Awesome! This is the correct answer. I'm glad you guys took interest and solved my first puzzle. :)

Answer (score 8):

Partial answer, not seeing how they all fit together...

I am an involuntary action
I will make you cry
If you force me to stop

> **Blinking**, an involuntary action, trying not to blink will make your eyes water.

I am also a knave
of excavation
and of luck

> **The Jack of Spades** in a deck of cards. Jacks are also called "Knaves". A spade is used for excavation, or digging. And various cards represent luck - the ace of spades is regarded as lucky.

I am also a soldier
you can't find me in the heavens
you can't find me in the seas

> Not 100% sure but I think this is talking about **infantry**, soldiers on the ground (as opposed to navy on the seas and airforce in the skies). Maybe you are looking for another synonym of infantry.

In a lifetime
and upon a time
I am what's missing

> **Once** is the missing word from the idioms "once in a lifetime" and "once upon a time".

Comment: You are on the right track. You got two of them right. The four answers would fit together.

Comment: Your answer for part 2 could be seen as doing part 1.

Answer (score 6):

I may have used a crowbar for a shoehorn here, but I somehow managed to cram into each part..

> **the number eleven.**

I am an involuntary action
I will make you cry
If you force me to stop

> Involuntary Bankruptcy means that someone is forcing you to stop by legal action. In the US, it's covered by Title 11.

I am also a knave
of excavation
and of luck

> Jack (numeric value 11) of spades (for excavation); card games are usually based on luck

I am also a soldier
you can't find me in the heavens
you can't find me in the seas

> Soldier 11; you can find them on the ground, because [they are shoes](https://www.nike.com/us/en_us/c/basketball/lebron-soldier-11).

In a lifetime
and upon a time
I am what's missing

> The word "once" (eleven in Spanish) is missing from both phrases.

Comment: Seeing crowbars used as seahorns is where I derive 90% of the fun from this site!

Comment: Cool answer. Your answers fit so well, however, it's not the one I'm looking for. The one I'm looking for is so much simpler. You got one of them right.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> Breathing

First part:

> Unless you noticed it and start breathing by your own will, breathing is an involuntary action. If you stop breathing (force it to stop) you will suffer a lot, ergo, you will start crying.

Second part:

> This one is tricky. Breathing can be a huge trouble on close spaces, such as the ones you can find out while in an excavation. So, yes, i'll stick to it.

Third part:

> At high altitudes, it gets really difficult to breath and we can only hold our breath while underwater.

Once again, sorry for my bad english!

Comment: the last hint remain unexplained.

Comment: I'm thinking about it :c

Answer (score 0):

So number one

> ***Blinking*** is the only thing I can think of that makes you cry if you stop, other than maybe *coughing*.

Two

> Ace of spades is lucky and spades are a digging implement, also ***jack of spades*** is also a knave.

Three

> Two possibilities I can think of, ***the*** **army**, as airforce and navy are ‘heavens and seas’ though I feel like ***ants*** also fits, as they are soldiers of the land. To be honest, this is probably the most vague of the four.

Four

> ***Once*** is missing from ‘upon a time’ and ‘in a lifetime’.

You mentioned in a comment that the four clues fit together, do you mean they form a sentence or are clues for a single word?